# Add a query string(s) at end of url using routes in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add query string(s) to the end of an url using routes. How do I do this in Global.asax ?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Detail",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
    new
    {
        action = "Detail",
        name = UrlParameter.Optional,
        // it is possible to add here query string(s) ?
    },
    new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
);
```

For example, the actual url contains:

```
www.mysite.com/MyController/Detail/4/MyValue
```

but I want to generate something like:

```
www.mysite.com/MyController/Detail/4/MyValue?ref=test&other=something
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you generate action URLs, you can pass in additional route values, like this:

```
@Url.Action("Detail", "MyController",
    new { id = 4, @ref = "test", other = "something" })
```

The `ref` and `other` parameters, which are not defined in the route template of the `Detail` route, will be appended as query string parameters.

Comment: I will use anyway the `Url.Action`, I didn't found the solution to put automatically in Global.asax

Answer (score 2):

MVC.NET automatically binds parameters from query string to your controller action input.

Example of your controller action would be like:

```
public ActionResult Detail(string id, string name, string test, string other){

}
```

Also, you can generate the link using a code like the following:

```
UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var url = helper.RouteUrl("Detail", new {id="testid", name="testname", ref="testref", other="testother"});
```